# How to mirror a gene sequence using perl

Tags: perl, match, mirror

So my question is how do you mirror a gene sequence in perl? Basically I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
 m/(([ACGT]{4})\2)/
```

this matches any of the four letters in a row 4 times *2... so ex: CGAG CGAG (without the space). How do I get this code to print out CGAG followed by GAGC instead of CGAG (the mirror of the second one? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would you give us a samle of input and desired output for a few scenarios ?

Answer (score 1):

pff, true-regexp way is:

```
m/(([ACGT]{4})\s*(??{ my $b = reverse $2; $b }))/

perl -E 'warn "CGAG GAGC" =~ m/(([ACGT]{4})\s*(??{ my $b = reverse $2; $b }))/'
CGAG GAGCCGAG at -e line 1.
```

But it is an experimental feature yet...

you can do smth like

```
my $str = "CGAGGAGC";
index($str, $1 . reverse($1)) != -1 && print "$1" . reverse($1) . " at " . (pos($str) - 4) while $str =~ m/([ACGT]{4})/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reverse` & `split` :

```
$ perl -le 'print reverse split //, "GAGC"'
CGAG
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you want to find a [palindromic secuence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_sequence).

In your case you can do something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.014;

my $dna = "TGCACGAGGAGCTTAC";

my ($match) = $dna =~ m/(([ACGT])([ACGT])([ACGT])([ACGT])\5\4\3\2)/;

say $match
#CGAGGAGC
```